# how to sort a list column wise on UI in django html

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a list of names. From django view.py function i am rendering it on UI.

```
names=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h...]
return render(request, 'show_names_list.html', names)
```

On UI i want to show it as

```
Names
a    d    g
b    e    h
c    f
```

My show_names_list.html looks like:

```
<span>Names</span>
<div class="mr-l15">
{%for item in names%}
    <span>{{item}} </span>
{% endfor %}
```

It gives me:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
g   h   i   j
```

Can anyone please help with the html part, where i can get the names in correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many items you want per column this template tag may be useful for splitting into vertical lists. This may work best in combination with bootstrap - using "col-md-2", for example:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2"><ul>
{% for item in names %}

{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:"3" %}
</ul></div>
<div  class="col-md-2"><ul>
{% endif %}

<li>{{ item }}</li>
{% endfor %}

</ul></div>
```

Comment: Hey,It just prints all the names in in a single column. how can i break and start the new column say after 5 names in each column.

Comment: You should be able to use some CSS on the divs or uls to put the lists (which are separated every 3 if you look at the source) into different columns. Change the "3" on the 4th line to a "5" and you'll start a new column every 5 items instead of every 3.

Comment: can you please help me with the css because a have tried everything a can but not able to end the column and start new column. All the names are coming in a single column.

Comment: Once you do that, you can add a .col-md-* class to each div (editing to show) and surround in a row div.

Comment: thnx mate. It was really helpful.  I am surely going to sit and learn css once i finish this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Re-grouping the items in the list can help.

In the view

```
from itertools import zip_longest

names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
gr = [iter(names)]*3 # 3 is the number of rows
gb = zip(*zip_longest(*gr))
new_names = [ el for t in gb for el in t if el ]
return render(request, 'show_names_list.html', new_names)
```

Now `names` is

```
['a', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'b', 'e', 'h', 'c', 'f', 'i']
```

and you can try what happens in the template.

Alternatively, we can do:

in the view

```
from itertools import zip_longest

names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']
gr = [iter(names)]*3 # 3 is the number of rows
gb = zip(*zip_longest(*gr))
return render(request, 'show_names_list.html', gb)
```

and in the template

```
<span>Names</span>
<div class="mr-l15">
{%for row in names %}
 {%for item in row %}
    <span>{{ item|default:"" }} </span>
 {% endfor %}
 <br>
{% endfor %}
```